# Oracle NVL function equivalent in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an Oracle NVL function equivalent in JavaScript/jQuery. I would be interested to see an example of how it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Ternary operator](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm) typically is used here.

For example, if you're creating a dynamic action in Apex you can do something like this:

```
( $v("P1_VAL1") ? $v("P1_VAL1") : $v("P1_VAL2") )
```

This will return the value of `P1_VAL1` if it's not blank, otherwise it will return the value of `P1_VAL2`.

Answer (score 13):

In Javascript this can actually be handled by the `||` operator, that returns the first "valid" value.

```
var a = null;
var b = "valid value";
var c = a || b; // c == "valid value"
```

Just keep in mind that ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values are not only `null` but also for example empty string `''`, number `0` and boolean value `false`. So you need to be sure that either you consider those with the same meaning as `null` or your variables cannot assume those values, because in those cases you will also get the second value selected:

```
var a = "";
var b = "valid value";
var c = a || b; // c == "valid value"
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it doesn't require the targeted expression to be repeated, which is a true equivalent of NVL. If the target expression is long and unwieldy, or performs some other calculation or transformation on the fly, I don't won't to repeat it.

Answer (score 6):

## Nullish coalescing operator (??)

The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
var foo = null ?? 'default string';
console.log(foo);
// expected output: "default string"
```

---

```js
var baz = 0 ?? 42;
console.log(baz);
// expected output: 0
```

Comment: but careful about browser compatibility.. i'll go with the traditional  Conditional (ternary) operator (?:)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 3):

```js
function nvl(value1,value2){
   if (value1 == null)
      return value2;
   
   return value1;
}
```