# Is there any alternative function in jquery like NULLIF() in sql server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

Is there any alternative function in jquery like NULLIF() in sql server?Is there any alternative function in jquery like NULLIF() in sql server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle NVL function equivalent in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167616/oracle-nvl-function-equivalent-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @PM77-1 NULLIF and NVL are not the same

Answer (score -1):

The isnull function will replace null values.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
ISNULL(Weight, 0)

You can also use Coalesce.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
COALESCE(Class, Color, ProductNumber) AS FirstNotNull

Comment: The question was about NULLIF, not either of those.  NULLIF returns NULL if the value under test is something specific,  or the value otherwise. And the Q was about how to implement it in java script anyway